# Tkinter Modify OptionMenu background?

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day, 
I'm not a programmer, and certainly horrible with anything related to Python - so I apologize if this is kind of ridiculous.

Trying to create a pretty basic UI with some text entry, labels, and some OptionMenus (tkinter).

Am attempting to change the background color of the OptionMenu widget using

```
OptionMenu.configure(bg="blue")
```

Unfortunately, I get the error

> TypeError: configure() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'self'

From what I've read, people get this when they're missing something in a class or not instantiated the class.  Not only don't I have a clue what that means, but I'm not creating any classes.  At least not that I'm aware of.

Any idea why I'd be getting that error and how to fix it?
I know I've got MUCH bigger fish to fry (like how to use the values after they are entered in the text boxes), but baby steps...

Oh, and if it matters I'm using Python 3.6 and Spyder.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to call the `.configure()` method on your particular OptionMenu, NOT the `OptionMenu` class itself.

Comment: That did it... thank you so much!  Odd that it reverts back to default gray when mouse runs over it, but that's not a big deal.

Really appreciate your help

Comment: It's `bg`, not `bf`...  Note that your code fragment is broken: it assigns to `C1` the result of calling `.configure()` (which is `None`), NOT the OptionMenu itself.  But you can put configuration options directly in the creation of the widget: try `C1 = OptionMenu(root, variable1, *optionsx, bg="blue")`

Comment: Ah, sorry for the typo - and thanks again.

I replaced my C1 line with yours above, but am getting error
"TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing"

Which is the same as when I try to modify the existing line
C1 = OptionMenu(*(root, variable1) + tuple(optionsx), bg="blue")

You've wasted enough or your time on this, and I'm absolutely grateful.  If the users have to have gray buttons, they'll be okay... was really more for my own desire to make a python based UI (could be done super easily in VBA, where I'm most comfortable).
Really, sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated by Jason in the comments above, you need to use `.configure()` on the object you want to configure not the class.

See below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar(root)
var.set(1)

array = [1, 2, 3]

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *array)
option.configure(background="white")

option.pack()
```

Additionally you can use the attribute `activebackground` to configure the colour of the background after the initial click on the `OptionMenu, this can be done like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar(root)
var.set(1)

array = [1, 2, 3]

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *array)
option.configure(background="white", activebackground="white")

option.pack()
```

If you wanted to go even further for consistency's sake you can actually configure the "dropdown menu" background colour too by calling the object's key `menu`. This can be done like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar(root)
var.set(1)

array = [1, 2, 3]

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *array)
option.configure(background="white", activebackground="white")
option["menu"].configure(bg="white")

option.pack()
```

Comment: This is all really great and helpful information - thank you all again!

Comment: If this answers your question please can you mark it as accepted so that future users can find an answer to similar questions.